# How could I include a custom Look and Feel with my application

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I have a found a 3rd party Look and Feel which I would really like to use with my application. I have successfully installed it (and it works) inside the JRE but most people (obviously) don't have it installed.

So I must find a way to include it with my application. Any idea on how I might do this ? From what I've understood, the CLASSPATH must contain the path to it, but I have no idea if modifying the CLASSPATH when the program is installing is even possible.

FYI: I do have access to both the .jar file with the Look-and-Feel and its source code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's the same as any other library.  How are you distributing your application?  Whatever packager you're using will specify how to add libraries to the classpath.

Comment: I'm using Inno Setup to package my application into an installer. I will have to see if it offers the possibility of changing the CLASSPATH. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: The CLASSPATH environment variable should not be changed. The installer should provide an executable wrapper or a startup script which launches java with the appropriate classpath: `java -cp yourJar.jar;lnf.jar com.foo.bar.Main`. A Java installer that would not be able to do this would be useless.

Comment: *"3rd party Look and Feel"*  Which one?  Many of them offer a [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) extension.  That makes it very easy to use the PLAF in your app.

Comment: It's this one: http://www.jtattoo.net/index.html . Don't know what that JWS extension is, though...

Comment: I had a look around their site and do not see a JWS extension offered.  Very low-tech.  Note that people only get notified of comment replies if you start them with `@Andrew` (etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution: I add the relative path to the .jar file that contains the LookandFeel in the Manifest of my application. So the manifest looks something like this:

```
Main-Class: MainClassName
Class-Path: Relative/Path/To/The/Library/With/The/LookAndFeel.jar
```

I applied this and it works.

Can't believe I didn't think of this earlier...

PS: Be careful as to not use spaces in the relative path. It won't work if you do so.